# Node installation on Windows - Can't run NPM from command prompt

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, installation

I have installed Node on my Windows 7 laptop (v6.9.1) and it is working but Node Package Manager will not run when I execute the npm.cmd.  I have verified the environment variables and both the nodejs and npm directories are in my PATH.  The error I receive is

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
/F was unexpected at this time.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with npm.cmd since the error comes from cmd.exe which processes it. Have you tried to reinstall node? You need to uninstall and then make sure to delete npm folder in c:/users/<you>/appdata/roaming to ensure the npm.cmd is created again.

Comment: Yes, I uninstalled and reinstalled several times.  Unfortunately that did not resolve the issue even when I remove the directory.

Comment: Is the npm.cmd you're trying to run from C:\Program Files\nodejs? If so can you try to run *npm -v* in different folder? C:/ for example

Comment: Running from the root C:\ still I get the same error as above.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new profile and reinstalling Node cleared up the issue.  Still not sure what the root cause of the issue was.

Comment: On behalf of another user without commenting privileges who needed clarification in order to use your solution: What kind of "profile" did you create anew?  Are you talking about a Windows user logon profile or something within python?